# restricting access on sql server to "my" views

Tags: sql-server, permissions, view

I am a college professor, and am facing a difficult permissions problem with SQL Server 2008.  My students need to complete a project using AdventureWorks, which involves building a series of views.  My problem is that I need to restrict access so that the students only see the views they have created.  I dont want them to see other students' work.  If this is too difficult, then I at least would like to restrict them from opening other students' design view.

Many thanks!

Mark

Comment: Because you cannot grant or deny permissions against an object that does not yet exist (AFAIK) - one way you might accomplish this is to create a schema for each student.

Answer (score 0):

As MarkD suggested in his comment, if you give each student their own schema, you should be able to solve this easily enough. For instance:

```
create schema Student1 authorization dbo;
create user Student1 with default_schema = Student1;
grant control on schema::Student1 to Student1; --full permissions on their own schema
```

Then, on your schema, grant whatever permissions you want them to have (select, view definition, etc).